# Undefined references using pagesel in Latex

Tags: latex

Let's say I have some labels in a part of the document that I exclude using pagesel. However, I want to reference them in the part that I am including. How is that possible?

Below is a minimum example which should print "This is reference 1", but instead prints "This is reference ??".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[files,2-]{pagesel} 

\title{Pagesel problem}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is label \label{ref:label1}.

\cleardoublepage

This is reference \ref{ref:label1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retain the labels from pages not shown by first compiling your whole document without the `pagesel` package and then, in a second step, use the `pagesel` package with the default `nofile` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
%files,
2-]{pagesel} 

\title{Pagesel problem}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is label \label{ref:label1}.

\cleardoublepage

This is reference \ref{ref:label1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other possible approach: compile the complete document and then use a tool like `pdftk` to extract the pages you like.